# Create inner divs within a loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom, foreach

Can someone explain to me how I do appending divs currently it just concats everything and it all looks like a mess. I want each trip to be inside separate `divs`

```
        var origin = ' ';
        var destination = ' ';
        var distance = ' ';
        var oneConcatedTrip = ' ';

        var outerDiv = document.getElementById('demo');
        var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var i = 1;

        var query = firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid +'/waypoints/Work/2016/06').orderByKey();            

        query.once("value")
          .then(function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

            var key = childSnapshot.key;
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();

            origin = childSnapshot.val().origin;    
            destination = childSnapshot.val().destination;  
            distance = childSnapshot.val().distance;

            innerDiv.className = 'block-' + i++;
            outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

            oneConcatedTrip =  origin + '  ' + destination + '  ' + distance;   
            innerDiv.innerHTML += oneConcatedTrip;

        });

            outerDiv.textContent = innerDiv.innerHTML;  
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reusing the same reference of `innerDiv`. You need to create different new `div` for every trip.

Move : `var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');` into the for loop.

Check example below :

**Your code** :

Note the `innerDiv` has a *blue* border and its only one box that you can see.

```js
var outerDiv = document.getElementById('demo');
var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  innerDiv.className = 'block';
  outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

  var oneConcatedTrip = 'origin   destination   distance';
  innerDiv.innerHTML += oneConcatedTrip;
}
```

```css
.block {
  border: 2px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

---

**Correct Way**

Now that for every iteration there is a new div, note that there are different boxes and not just one.

```js
var outerDiv = document.getElementById('demo');
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
  innerDiv.className = 'block';
  outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);

  var oneConcatedTrip = 'origin   destination   distance';
  innerDiv.innerHTML += oneConcatedTrip;
}
```

```css
.block {
  border: 2px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

Comment: aha I see! I had it inside the loop first but for some reason I moved it. Thanks a lot!